# Why replace is not saved?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Trying to translate for image addresses, found the replace function for sql
doing

```
SELECT product_id, REPLACE(image, 'к', 'k') as text FROM oc_product;
```

It gives the result supposedly everything is replaced - I update the page - everything is as before ...

https://www.dropbox.com/s/kz3x55lwprauti9/Ub97uw5x42.mp4?dl=0

Comment: A `select` query does not permanently change the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are trying to achieve it's an UPDATE:

```
UPDATE oc_product SET image = REPLACE(image, 'к', 'k');
```

Be careful since you don't have a WHERE clause in this query.

Comment: then add `WHERE image like '%к%';` should suffice